# Nuxt - REST API call in static build

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to create a web app that requires authentication for all users (login page). Can I use the static build for such applications? or I need a Universal build?  I need to call web API almost on every page like Clint listing, Client Detail, News Feed, etc..

Could you please suggest which approach suits my app the most? Universal or Static?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You can use any, add your authentication call to middleware, this middleware will be called anytime when a page reloads.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can my middleware handle fetching of newly added clients by REST API call to the server? I mean after creating a static production build (Generate) can I still be able to make REST API call to my server?

Comment: Yea, thats what middleware does. All the middleware will be executed before the page loads.